# revert / rollback a configuration with netmiko

Tags: python, configuration, config, revert, netmiko

hey i am trying to set a config revert on every config commands i send to netmiko. cant manage to find any solution for doing that task.
i want to set a time which if the configuration isnt complete then it will revert to before the configuration.

tried to use NAAS and send "configure terminal revert timer 1" and then a random config command but it seems netmiko expects a specific output from each command so it falls after i send it. i cant change the netmiko setting because i need to update it once in a while

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following code using the NAPALM's `device.rollback()` feature. You can do it this way too.

```
from napalm import get_network_driver
driver = get_network_driver('eos')
device = driver('ip_address', 'username', 'password')
device.open()

device.load_replace_candidate(filename='device.conf')
print (device.compare_config())

if len(device.compare_config()) > 0:
    choice = input("\nWould you like to Replace the Configuration file? [yN]: ")
    if choice == 'y':
        print('Committing ...')
        device.commit_config()

        choice = input("\nWould you like to Rollback to previous config? [yN]: ") 
        if choice == 'y':
            print('Rollback config is in progress ...')
            device.rollback()  
    else:
        print('Discarding ...')
        device.discard_config()
else:
    print ('No difference')

device.close()
print('Done.')
```

Resource: https://napalm.readthedocs.io/en/develop/tutorials/changing_the_config.html